# Is there a WPF control which supports VirtualizedItemPattern?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ui-automation

I'm trying to implement a way to fetch all items from ListView with enabled virtualization for testing purposes. But apparently, despite the fact that Microsoft states that all controls since WPF 4 which supports virtualization have to have VirtualizedItemPattern implemented so a developer will be able to fetch all items from a container without implicit scrolling of the container.

My simple WPF application has ListView item inside Window element with added in the code-behind 100 elements. According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486373%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), my expectation is that I'm able to get VirtualizedItemPattern from the ListView and call Realize() method to make the virtual item fully accessible as a UI Automation element. But the attempt to do it throws "Unsupported pattern" exception.

Well, the next my thought was like, maybe I made a mistake with choosing an item container and realized that none of those containers I tried is supporting this "feature".

And at this point, I completely stuck, since there is no documentation on this and no any examples. What happened with this feature? Has it been obsoleted? Any OS/some limitations (I tried on W7 and W10)?

Update:
Ways I've tried to populate ListView:

```
var _list = Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(i => i.ToString());

foreach (var item in _list)
{ 
  List.Items.Add(item);
}
```

then I had thought the problem might be in how I'm populating the control, so I decided to try ItemsSource

```
List.ItemsSource = _list;
```

In both cases, I got the same result - no way to get all items through UI automation framework.

Comment: "with added in the code-behind 100 elements", how are you doing that? Please show us some code.

Comment: @Clemens, thanks for the response. Pls see an update in the description.

Comment: I believe you would need to use a `ObservableCollection` for the `VirtualizationPattern` to be able to `Realize()` the items.